# How can I change the folding styles for Vim's built-in highlighing for Markdown?

Tags: vim, markdown, folding

The default styling for folded headers in Vim's built-in Markdown highlighting is a whitish background, which is very difficult to visually scan.

How can I change the background color of lines that are folded Markdown headers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change folded highlight style by setting the `Folded` highlight group.
In order to change background colour of a highlight group you need to change `ctermbg` (for Terminal Vim) or `guibg` (for Gvim).

For example, to change folded background to white:

```vim
:highlight Folded ctermbg=15
```

You can use `:hi` instead of the full command name `:highlight`.

You need to specify colour number for `ctermbg` and list of acceptable values can be found in `:h highlight-ctermbg`.

For changing folded backgound colour in GUI Vim (GVim), you need to use `guibg`:

```vim
:hi Folded guibg=white
```

You can check list of acceptable values for `guibg` here:
`:h gui-colors`

#### Make it persistent

Using `:highlight` (`:hi` in abbrev) command in the current session changes highlight settings for the current session only.

It would be recommended to use `autocommand` to make it persistent.

```vim
augroup MyGroup
  autocmd ColorScheme * hi Folded ctermbg=15 guibg=white
augroup END
```

Additional information

You can put `hi Folded ctermbg=15 guibg=white` in your `.vimrc` to make background colour of folded lines white.
However, with this, the `:hi` command is invoked when you open Vim or .vimrc is reloaded by `:source` command.
So your highlight settings will be reset if you change the colorscheme in the session.
With the `autocmd` why above, the autocmd is invoked if the `ColorScheme` event is fired (= colorscheme is changed).

Comment: Thank you so much. However, I am seeing this error with all these approaches: E530: Cannot change term in GUI: term=linux

Comment: If you use GVim only you can just take `cterm` away from the command line. `autocmd ColorScheme * hi Folded guibg=white`

Comment: Final links looked like: "autocmd ColorScheme * hi Folded guibg=#191919" (to match Macvim's dark mode background)
and "autocmd ColorScheme * hi Folded guifg=LightGray"

Answer (score 0):

Using `hi [group] ctermbg=[color] guibg=[color]` to change highlighting background for a group.

`:h :hi` for more usage.

If you don't know the highlight group name of the folded markdown headers. Run `:echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')` to get text highlight group names under cursor.